# Entity Framework query joins and group by issue

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, entity-framework-5, oracle11gr2

Please correct the query

IN PL/SQL

```
SELECT a.MENU_ID, a.menu_label, a.menu_value  
FROM tbl_ims_menu a, TBL_IMS_ROLE_ASSIGNED_MENU b,TBL_IMS_USER_ROLE_PRIVILEGES c 
WHERE a.menu_id = b.menu_id   AND b.urole_id = c.granted_role   
                              AND c.user_id = '3'   AND a.menu_master <> '0'  
                              AND a.menu_status = 'Active' 
GROUP BY a.menu_id, a.menu_label, a.menu_value
```

query is working fine there is some issue when rewrite in Entity framework

check the following query

```
List<TBL_IMS_MENU> listSubMenu = (from m in db.TBL_IMS_MENU   
                                  join ra in db.TBL_IMS_ROLE_ASSIGNED_MENU on m.MENU_ID 
                                  equals ra.MENU_ID   
                                  join rp in db.TBL_IMS_USER_ROLE_PRIVILEGES on ra.UROLE_ID
                                  equals rp.GRANTED_ROLE   
                                  where rp.USER_ID == UserID   
                                  group m by m.MENU_ID
                                  into g select g).ToList();
```

if I used Var instead of List  then how to fire loop?

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: var keyword is just type inference. Type of the query after calling ToList() will be IEnumerable, so you can enumerate it like you do it with List.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove your `join` statements - and just use the `where` like you do in raw SQL query:

```
var qry  = (from a in db.TBL_IMS_MENU   
            from b in db.TBL_IMS_ROLE_ASSIGNED_MENU 
            from c in db.TBL_IMS_USER_ROLE_PRIVILEGES 

            where c.USER_ID == UserID
            where b.UROLE_ID == c.GRANTED_ROLE
            where a.MENU_ID  == b.MENU_ID 
            where a.menu_status == "Active" 
            where a.menu_master != "0" 
            select a)
           .GroupBy(c => c.menu_id)
              .ThenBy(c => c.menu_label)
                .ThenBy(c => c.menu_value)
           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var listSubMenu = (from m in db.TBL_IMS_MENU   
                                  join ra in db.TBL_IMS_ROLE_ASSIGNED_MENU on m.MENU_ID 
                                  equals ra.MENU_ID   
                                  join rp in db.TBL_IMS_USER_ROLE_PRIVILEGES on ra.UROLE_ID
                                  equals rp.GRANTED_ROLE   
                                  where rp.USER_ID == UserID   
                                  group m by new { m.MENU_ID, m.menu_label, m.menu_value }
                                  into g select g).ToList();

foreach(var groupItem in listSubMenu)
{
   // go through groups like this - groupItem.Key.MENU_ID
   foreach(var menuItem in grouItem)
   {
       //go through each item in group like this - menuItem.GRANTED_ROLE
   }
}
```